# Perl dbi sqlite 'select * ..' only returns first elem

Tags: perl, sqlite, select, dbi

got a problem with perl dbi sqlite.

I have set up a database (and checked it with sqlite command line).
Now i want to search in this database, which did not work.

So i tried to just do a 'SELECT *'
this prints **only the first element** in the database, but not as it should everything in this table.

I think the error that causes the select * to fail is the same that prevents me from using "like %..%" stuff.

This is the relevant code, if the code is correct and the database table seems good what else could have caused the problems ?

```
 my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbfile","","") || die "Cannot connect: $DBI::errstr";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM words');
$sth->execute;
my @result = $sth->fetchrow_array();


foreach( @result) {
    print $_;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**fetchrow_array**() only fetches one row.

Try

```
while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
  print "@row\n";
}
```

Comment: You should add `strict`ures to your answer to improve it. Otherwise, you're spot on.

Answer (score 6):

According to [`the documentation`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#Statement-Handle-Methods), `fetchrow_array`

> Fetches the next row of data and returns it as a list containing the field values.

If you want *all* of the data you can call `fetchrow_array` (or `fetchrow_arrayref`) repeatedly until you reach the end of the table, or you can use `fetchall_arrayref`:

> The fetchall_arrayref method can be used to fetch all the data to be returned from a prepared and executed statement handle. It returns a reference to an array that contains one reference per row

The code would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbfile = 'words.db';

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbfile", '', '') or die "Cannot connect: $DBI::errstr";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM words');
$sth->execute;
my $result = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;

foreach my $row ( @$result ) {
  print "@$row\n";
}
```

Comment: There is an error in the code at the password argument for DBI->connect()